# CSS Grid min-content not fitting content

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to put some divs in a grid by explicitly assigning rows, columns, and sizes to the elements and allowing CSS grid to do column and row sizing work using the following CSS.

```
display: grid;
grid-auto-columns: min-content;
```

The value `min-content` is supposed to set columns to be the smallest possible size that fits the content without overflow. However, this is not happening. Even though these elements can all fit in a 350px grid, the third column is too large causing unnecessary whitespace.

Here is an image of what is going on.

[image: Image With Gridlines]

And here is the actual code: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bamazap/6jkLngmk/)

```js
function randint(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

const children = document.getElementById('parent').children;
const skip = 360 / children.length;
let value = randint(0, 359);
for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i += 1) {
  const elm = children[i];
  elm.style.backgroundColor = `hsl(${value}, 100%, 85%)`;
  value += skip;
  elm.id = "w" + (i + 1);
  const style = window.getComputedStyle(elm);
  elm.innerHTML = `width: ${elm.offsetWidth}px<br \>
  col: ${style.getPropertyValue('grid-column')}<br \>
  row: ${style.getPropertyValue('grid-row')}`;
}
```

```css
#parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: min-content;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 350px;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

#parent>div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 75px;
}

#w1 {
  width: 200px;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

#w2 {
  width: 150px;
  grid-column: 3 / 5;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

#w3 {
  width: 100px;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

#w4 {
  width: 150px;
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

#w5 {
  width: 100px;
  grid-column: 4 / 5;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to work fine in Firefox, could be a browser bug?

Comment: I just downloaded Firefox (for Mac) and it behaves the same as Chrome for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grid items in the first row create four columns:

```
#w1 {
  width: 200px;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

#w2 {
  width: 150px;
  grid-column: 3 / 5;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}
```

The first item spans two columns (`grid-column: 1 / 3`).

The second item spans two columns (`grid-column: 3 / 5`).

So you have a 4-column grid.

---

### Chrome

In Chrome, the lengths of the grid items in the first row are divided equally between columns.

So the first two columns are 100px wide:

[image]

And the second two columns are 75px wide:

[image]

Now you can see what's happening on the second row. Here's the code:

```
#w3 {
  width: 100px;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

#w4 {
  width: 150px;
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

#w5 {
  width: 100px;
  grid-column: 4 / 5;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}
```

- The first item (`#w3`) is 100px wide. That fits perfectly into the first column created by `#w1`.
- The second item (`#w4`) is 150px wide. 100px fits perfectly into the second column created by `#w1`. Another 50px extends into the third column, which was created by `#w2` and is 75px wide. **That leaves a 25px gap, representing leftover space in the third column.**
- The third item (`#w5`) is 100px wide. But since it starts at the fourth column, which is 75px wide, the remaining 25px overflows the container.

***Bottom line:*** *In Chrome, the width of the columns are fixed once the first row is rendered. Grid items in subsequent rows respect the column widths established in the first row.*

---

### Firefox

Unlike in Chrome, in Firefox it appears that column widths don't remain fixed after rendering the first row. Column widths are flexible throughout the rendering process.

[image]

---

### Edge

Same as Chrome.

Comment: Is there a reason for the difference between Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: My best guess at the moment is just a fallback to: There are multiple rendering differences between Chrome and Firefox. They are different browsers. They have different development teams. That's why developers have to test continuously across browsers. @sol

Comment: Actually, I don't think it's the first row. If I flip the rows the issue does not get solved.

Comment: Can you post a demo with your flipped rows? Not exactly sure how you altered the set-up.

Comment: I see what you mean. I don't have time at the moment to research the *Grid Item Placement Algorithm*, but you may want to take a look: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#auto-placement-algo